# Fitting parabolic shape to data (is it possible to use logic statements with SciPy CurveFit?)

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I’m trying to fit data with a parabola shape of the form: 
**Y(x) = a(1 – (x/b)^2)    for |x| < b .......
Y(x) = 0 otherwise**
And I’ve added in two extra degrees of freedom so the parabola can be horizontally and vertically shifted.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def parabolic(self, t, *p): 
    a, b, c, d = p        
    if abs(t) > b:
        return 0
    else:
        return a*(1-(((t-c)/b)**2)) + d
```

I’m trying to use curve_fit from scipy.optimize and have created a parabolic function, which I then try to fit with using:

```
coeff, cov = curve_fit(parabolic, data[:,0], data[:,1], p0) #Return co-effs for fit and      covariance, p0 = user given seed fitting parameters
```

The script returns an error though related to using logic in my parabolic fit definition. When I remove the logic statement and just fit to the entire data (which is a background noise level with a parabolic shape in the centre), the results are awful as the fit tries to include the background noise level.

All suggestions welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell without the exact error, but try adding an `import numpy as np` and replace `abs` with `np.abs`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it returned the same error for the line:
if np.abs(t) > b:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I think the problem arises because I pass an array of values for the variable t. I tried replacing t with t.all() and also with t.any() - both options give a fit but it's awful as I assume it tries to fit to the whole data which is mostly a background level with just a parabolic shape in the centre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do it like this:

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

def parabola(t, *p): 
    a, b, c, d = p
    y = np.zeros(t.shape)
    indices = np.abs(t) < b
    y[indices] = (a*(1-(((t[indices]-c)/b)**2)) + d)
    return y

p0 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 20)
y = parabola(x, *p0)
coeff, cov = curve_fit(parabola, x, y, p0)
print(coeff)
```

**Update**

With the provided data (see link in the comment), things start to become somewhat clearer:

- this is tricky data with respect to its behaviour. A lot of the "zero" data will not help fitting the function, since the weight of the actual function becomes less and less with more zero data. Often, the best is to cut down somewhat and concentrate on the relevant data (once you have that, you can try and fit all the data with your best-found parameters).
- The criterion is incorrect: it is centred around zero, not around the peak of the data (`c`).
- Having the parameters `b` and `c` in both the function and the criterion for the indices makes things harder: the function behaves less and less linearly. I found the initial best parameters by using a fixed criterion, which is the commented-out line below.
- Provide good starting parameters. `[1, 2, 3, 4]` are just very generic, which in case of non-linear least squares can make it hard to fit.

So, taking all of the above into account, I came up with this:

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def parabola(t, *p): 
    a, b, c, d = p
    y = np.zeros(t.shape)
    # The indices criterion was first fixed to values that appeared reasonably; 
    # otherwise the fit would completely fail.
    # Once decent parameters were found, I replaced 28 and 0.3 with the center `c` 
    # and the width `b`.
    #indices = np.abs(t-28) < 0.3
    indices = np.abs(t-c) < b
    y[indices] = (a*(1-(((t[indices]-c)/b)**2)) + d)
    return y

out = np.loadtxt('data.dat')
# Limit the data to only the interesting part of the data
# Once we have the fit correct, we can always attempt a fit to all data with 
# good starting parameters
xdata = out[...,0][450:550]
ydata = out[...,1][450:550]
# These starting parameters are either from trial fitting, or from theory
p0 = [2, 0.2, 28, 6.6]
coeff, cov = curve_fit(parabola, xdata, ydata, p0)
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, '.')
xfit = np.linspace(min(xdata), max(xdata))
yfit =  parabola(xfit, *coeff)
plt.plot(xfit, yfit, '-')
plt.show()
```

[image: Parabola fit]

Note that the resulting `b` parameter still indicates a bad fit. I'm guessing that the combination of these data and this function are just tricky. One option would be to iterate over various reasonable values of `b` (e.g., between 0.2 and 0.3) and find the best reduced chi-squared.

But, I also note that the data do not appear as a parabola. Initially, when I saw the full data picture, I thought "Gaussian", but that's not it either. It looks almost like a boxcar function.
If you have a good theoretical model that says it's a parabola, then either the data is off or the model may be incorrect. If you're just looking for a descriptive function, try a few other functions as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately this just fitted the data with a flat line. If it helps, I've put some test data here:
[link](http://pastebin.com/6W5h4vC0)

Also, my Python failed to find print_statement. What this does line do please?

Comment: My bad about the `print_statement`. That should be `print_function`, and I've fixed that in an edit. It's one of the things I use to make the code Python 2 and 3 compatible: it turns `print 'hello'` into `print('hello')`. Ditto for the `from __future__ import division`: the normal division now always returns a floating point, not integer division: `3/2 = 1.5`, not 1. [Here is](http://stackful-dev.com/quick-tips-on-making-your-code-python-3-ready.html) one short write-up on this, if you're curious.

Comment: I have now updated the answer with the data I've gotten through your link. That provided very insightful, so I hope this can help you further. Good luck

Comment: Thanks so much for the code and your explanation. I'll have a play around with it now.